# Why do I get exception while I read element from xml

Tags: xml, vb.net, nullreferenceexception

When I press the btnUpdate to show the specific elements from my XML file it shows exception error which says "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

```
Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
    Dim xelement As XElement = xelement.Load(cbFileName.Text)
    Dim Data As IEnumerable(Of XElement) = xelement.Elements()

    For Each dat In Data
        MsgBox(dat.Element("Name").Value & "...." & dat.Element("Tel").Value)
    Next dat
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evidently you have NullReferenceException. First, it must show you where it occured, i.e. line or variable, which is null.

The most probable source of error is that your `dat.Element` does not contain key `"Name"` or `"Tel"`. But I'd suggest you to take a closer look at exception message and stack trace.

Comment: Wow! what an obvious mistake! Yes you are right. The xml file wasn't contain name element ! Thanks!

Comment: But there is another things. The error is for MsgBox line . If it is included the name element I still get this error because after prompt shows me the first element it reads but if it cant find the other name element inside the file it shows me the exception again

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get what exactly is happening in there. In case you have an unhandled exception, Visual Studio wouldn't let you to continue executing your code, it will either stop your program or show exception once again.

Comment: Hence, I'd suggest you to put MsgBox into `Try ... Catch e as Exception` and set a breakpoint into `Catch` block. Then you will see, which exception you get and will be able to understand what's going on